# How to find .net framework of application?

Tags: .net, frameworks

I am working on scanner kind of application which takes different C# codebases as input.I want to know in which .net framework version(1.1/2.0/3.5/4.0) specific  codebase is built.

Can anybody provide me code to check .net framework version of codebases? can i read codebase version from .csproj file ? If yes, please provide code for same.

Thanks,

Teena.

Comment: `ildasm YourAssembly.dll /text | grep "Metadata version:"`

Answer (score 5):

Look for the `TargetFrameworkVersion` and `RequiredTargetFramework` attributes in the .csproj file: there's code [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/db705dcf-192c-490e-b34f-7d9546f91e4b/) to open and parse the project file.

Comment: We don't use project files, just use csc.exe to compile

Comment: @Zoli well this answer _is_ twelve years old..

Comment: No problem, but the original problem/question is still valid

Comment: So I suppose you want to work out which version of `csc.exe` to use? If though you don't have projects, though, then the Net  Framework version isn't defined anywhere..

Answer (score 2):

> Can anybody provide me code to check .net framework version of codebases? can i read codebase version from .csproj file ?

Use the [Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.aspx) class:

```
string projectFileName = ...
Project proj = new Project(projectFileName);
string version = proj.GetPropertyValue("TargetFrameworkVersion");
```

Comment: We don't use project files, just use csc.exe to compile

Comment: @Zoli don't. You're only making things harder for yourself. There's a whole SDK to build .NET applications, csc.exe being one of the lowest level tools of that SDK. You're not supposed to use csc.exe directly. This isn't 2002 (and even then you usually didn't need to use it directly...)

Comment: it's not an option, big multiplatform / multilanguage project, most of the do not even have projects files at all, everything is compiled by cl.exe / csc.exe / midl.exe / rc.exe / etc - by jam

Comment: Ouch, good luck with that. Sounds like a nightmare. Honestly, if I had to maintain an app like that, I would probably quit on the spot. (sorry, I realize that's not very helpful...)

Comment: Actually I like it, I know it inside-out (and no one else), but that's not related here...

Answer (score 2):

```
var document = XDocument.Load("ProjectName.csproj");
var targetFramework = document
    .Descendants(XName.Get("TargetFrameworkVersion", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"))
    .First()
    .Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

the cs proj file is an xml document

just open it and have a look you can parse it and work with it like any xml document.

Comment: We don't use project files, just use csc.exe to compile

Answer (score 0):

steps for windows application:

1) Right click on project that you want to know framework version.

2) Click on “Properties” or press “ALT+ENTER”.

3) Now click on “Compile” tab from tree view.

4) Click on “Advance Compile Options..” appear at bottom.

5) It opens Settings pop up and from that you can find out “Target Framework”. From that you can also change framework of your application and save settings. That’s it.

You can also refer following image for faster review:

[image]

[image]