# How to know which Framework requires a external application?

Tags: .net, windows, frameworks

How can I know which version of Framework requires to be installed in the PC to execute a application which is developed in .NET but not developed by myself?
How to know which version of FW needs that app?

Comment: is it really a question of a person who already got 1500+ points on stack 0_o?

Comment: Sorry, the question is ambiguous. I only wanted clarification. If he has the source code, you can check it out in Visual Studio, for example, if not check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325918/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-the-net-framework-an-executable-needs-to-run

Comment: @freak well you have the answer? not? then you are like me.

Comment: @ElektroHacker first make it a question then ask for answer

Comment: @Dave Rook I don't have the source that's why I don't know the targeting FW...

Comment: Please [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341912/how-to-find-net-framework-of-application).It may help you

Comment: @ElektroHacker, I didn't notice your score, no offense was meant by my question to clarify your post :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the decompiler dotPeek - it's free from JetBrains. This will show you after you decompile the exe.

However, as per my comments, check this post out on Stack Overflow [How to find out which version of the .NET Framework an executable needs to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325918/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-the-net-framework-an-executable-needs-to-run)

Answer (score 1):

It is easy using ILDASM ([description on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). Run it and open selected exe or dll. Select MANIFEST and open it (double click)
No try to find lines like this (for .NET 4.0):

```
// Metadata version: v4.0.30319
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
```

or like this (for .NET 2.0):

```
// Metadata version: v2.0.50727
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
```